# Create a variable with a value that is the name of another variable in R

Tags: r, vector, variable-names

In R, how can you create a variable that it's value is the name of another variable?

For example: I have the vector `groupers`:

```
groupers <- c("Epinephelus.costae", "Epinephelus.marginatus",
              "Mycteroperca.rubra", "Serranus.cabrilla", "Serranus.scriba")
```

and I'd like to create an output that would be like that:

```
grp_name <- "groupers"
```

This seems like a simple operation but I don't know how the name of a vector is stored and therefore I can't figure out how to call it.

Cheers

Comment: Why do you need this? You say that “This seems like a simple operation” but in reality it’s *extremely* complex, and most programming languages fundamentally don’t support this. R does, but there is almost always a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to take an object name and convert it to a character string, use this:

```
grp_name <- deparse(substitute(groupers))
grp_name
# [1] "groupers"
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine you do not only have a single vector but several. So you could assemble them in a dataframe and store the names of the dataframe columns calling the function `names()`:

```
groupers <- c("Epinephelus.costae", "Epinephelus.marginatus",
              "Mycteroperca.rubra", "Serranus.cabrilla", "Serranus.scriba")
group2 <- c("Epinephelus", "Epinephelus",
              "Mycteroperca", "Serranus", "Serranus")
```

Assemble the vectors in a dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(groupers, group2)
```

Store the names in a new vector:

```
groupnames <- names(df); groupnames
[1] "groupers" "group2"
```